# Trouble with web browsers

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, browser

Randomly one day I turn on my computer into Ubuntu and all of a sudden `firefox` (my browser of choice) keeps opening on its own, and if I let it will open 100+ instances of firefox so I had to uninstall it.

So then I try `google chrome` and it starts doing the same exact thing. So I uninstall that and try `chromium` and whadya know, same thing. Then I try opera and strangely enough, it works just fine.

But to my dismay I find opera to be a slow alternative, not very good and often unresponsive. So I really want to use `firefox` its my favourite browser. and this clearly seems to be a problem with the OS not the specific software. This problem makes my installation of `Ubuntu` virtually useless so if anyone has had this same problem or knows any sugestions it will be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: I can't say that I've experienced this issue with any Ubuntu PC I have installed and maintained.

Answer (score 0):

**Try these once hope it would help you**

1. First completely remove firefox with it's configuration file using following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove firefox
   sudo apt-get --purge remove firefox
   ```
2. Then remove the the `~/.mozilla` directory by using this command:

   ```
   rm -r ~/.mozilla
   ```

   <sub>It will remove the configuration file/history of firefox for the current user</sub>
3. Then re-install firefox using this:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install firefox
   ```

If it doesn't help then repeat the same procedure beginning from step 1, just replace the command in step 2 with this one:

```
sudo find / | grep -i firefox | sudo xargs rm -rf
```

Reply if something goes wrong..

**Alternated Way**

Run this command in terminal:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

Then under **Web Browser** chose some other browser as you told **Opera** is working fine, select that. Restart your system and check if it happens again..